# Azure Devops Git: Extract SQL query from JSON file?

Tags: sql, github, azure-devops, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

I'm commiting SQL script files to an Azure Devops Git repository. This is from within Synapse Serverless.

It works OK for restoring old versions of the SQL Scripts.

But sometimes I just want to see the old SQL script, or maybe grab it and run it manually.

The scripts are all there, but saved as JSON.

[image: There the scripts all are]

Open one up, and the query itself is all one line - and copy/paste doesn't even work due to the carriage return and linebreak symbols
[image]

I was able to write a Python script that will *extract & format* the SQL. But:

1. It requires downloading the JSON file / pointing the script at the
   file.
2. It...requires running a Python Script. It feels like there should be
   an easier, built-in-ish way that I'm missing.

Pasting code here, just in case it helps someone else who stumbles upon this post. Though again, I'm wondering if there isn't an easier way.

```
import json
import sqlparse

# Load the JSON file
with open(r"C:\YourPathToFile\TheFile.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Extract the SQL code from the JSON data
sql_code = data['properties']['content']['query']

# Replace the newline and carriage return characters
sql_code = sql_code.replace('\\n', '\n').replace('\\r', '\r')

# Format the SQL code
formatted_sql = sqlparse.format(sql_code, reindent=True, keyword_case='upper')

# Print the formatted SQL code
print(formatted_sql)
```

Comment: The easiest thing would be a button in DevOps that pulls the query out pastes it in SSMS and runs it. Thats possible but not praactical. Some options to consider are: paste the full path to the git item into your script and have it download the JSON from git, shred it and spit the SQL out. Or you could use TKinit to create a UI that lets you paste the GIT reference in. Or if you are using Azure Data Studio or VS Code, you could write a plugin that does all that...... which begs the question, is there already a VS Code plugin that does all this? What is your definition of "easy"?

Comment: @Nick.Mc Mostly I was thinking there was something built-in I was missing. But sounds like not- which is great to know.   Easier is anything that has 1.) Most importantly - less steps. 2.) Less importantly -  less dependencies (my 'solution' requires being able to run a Python script).  e.g. - a solution where one could "only" copy & paste the text into say, Notepad++ then run something that extracts & formats (thus saving the download & point-python-at-it steps) would be a bit better.  I'll explore the other things you mentioned as well. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend VS Code over notepad++ It's a lot more flexible, i.e. you'll find it has  a free Synapse extension which notepad++ will never have. Check it out, maybe it does what you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/data-engineering/setup-vs-code-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Git Repos is just a version control tool based on Git that help you to manage the files versions. It is not able to automatically parse and extract the SQL scripts from JSON file. There also is not built-in feature to do this.

To parse and extract the SQL scripts from JSON file, just like as you have been doing, you need to develop a script/application (can be written by any of PowerShell, Bash, Python, etc..) to read the content of JSON file, then parse and extract the SQL scripts from the content.

Comment: Is there a reason why SQL scripts are saved in git as JSON in the first place?

Comment: @Pingyao, Git will not convert the SQL scripts into JSON files. Git actually supports to store the `.sql` files. You mentioned the SQL scripts are from Synapse Serverless. How did you export/fetch the SQL scripts from Synapse Serverless? I'm afraid that the JSON files with the SQL scripts are directly exported from the Synapse Serverless and then pushed to the git repository.

Comment: @[Bright Ran-MSFT] yes exactly, one just clicks 'commit' in Synapse Serverless, and it's all automated.

Comment: Why stop at needing to first download the JSON file when you could also pull the JSON down from Git. It's all a matter of deciding on the entry point. With regards to why JSON? They needed to add extra metadata to the script such as folder etc. so they chose the defacto generic nested data format of JSON.